# install pdf reader on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

If a pdf reader is not installed in the browser ,from a web page how to make a user install pdf  reader on the page load with pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not be done in JavaScript. If the browsers allowed sites to install pdf viewers, what next? It would be a security nightmare.

You can not, and should not, *make* your users install anything. Indicate that the file requires a pdf viewer to view the document -- even a few links to free viewers -- and leave it at that.

Comment: @Rajeev, I'm sorry but there are not. Google, for example, does not install a pdf viewer on the client. It processes the pdf server-side displays the result in html (essentially a pdf->html converter)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in JavaScript, the browser will prompt the user to download the `.pdf` file if a reader isn't present (since it doesn't know what *else* to do with it), but installing *any* plugin is outside the purview of JavaScript - and should be - it would be a security nightmare.

What would you *make* them install, Adobe? :)